# Please explain how to use FPM + pleaserun to create a Linux service

Tags: fpm

My goal is to package a service as deb & rpm artifacts using FPM (v1.9.3). 
I would like to target Ubuntu 18.04 and Centos 7.
The service is comprised of an executable and multiple dll files.

The problem:
According to [FPM documentation](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pleaserun.html#one-package-for-all-platforms) I should use the "Pleaserun" source to create a universal service installer and the "dir" source to pack the files. 
Unfortunately, the combination does not work. The "Pleaserun" option overwrites all the rest of the flags and no dlls/executables are packaged.

I assume that my scenario is one of the basic use-cases. I would appreciate if you could share your working example of the command line invocation.

The following is the list of unanswered questions and directly related tickets that appear on the GitHub.

- [fpm + pleaserun: Documentation lacking](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/1529)
- [fpm + pleaserun: how-to use the .rpm or .deb generated](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/issues/1425)

Comment: Can you add the command you tried?

Comment: This is a good question; I'm surprised nobody has answered. The fpm API definitely supports this; you can see it in action in this PR - https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/pull/1234/files - but I don't know how to do this on the CLI.